# Azure pipelines builds started failing recently due to a new image/MSBuild

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-pipelines

We have an Azure build pipeline that has been working flawlessly for quite a while.  About a week ago builds on some agents started failing and now they all are.  Even builds on release branches that succeeded before are failing now.  Failure error is:

`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1118,5): error NETSDK1151: The referenced project '../***.DbInstaller.csproj' is a self-contained executable.  A self-contained executable cannot be referenced by a non self-contained executable.  For more information, see https://aka.ms/netsdk1151 [/home/vsts/work/1/s/application/***.PublicPortal.csproj]`

Now this is not a recent change - we had this setup in place for quite a while.  One suggestion is to add the following line in the project:

`<ValidateExecutableReferencesMatchSelfContained>false</ValidateExecutableReferencesMatchSelfContained>`

which fixes the builds but breaks our tests somewhere else.

Now I think this change might have something to do with a changed image and MSBuild version being used - here are the screenshots - noticed newer image and MSBuild version on failing builds:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what the problem might be?  Is there a way to force an older image to test my theory?

Comment: Regarding your description and conjecture, you could test with self-hosted agent to see if it works and also check to see whether it is the image version which affected with self-hosted agent.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the update of the [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md).

Recently, the .net version (.net7.0) and MSbuild(17.4.0) version have been updated in the Microsoft-hosted agent.

Currently, there is a known issue with .net 7.0 and msbuild 17.4.0. Refer to this ticket: [dotnet test does not forward MSBuild properties to msbuild in .NET 7 RC1](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/4014)

> Is there a way to force an older image to test my theory?

For a workaround, you can use the task: Use DotNet task to define the dotnet version 6.0.

For example:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
     packageType: 'sdk'
     version: '6.x'
```

Then the Msbuild task will use old version of build tool.

[image]